# Get Checkbox value in mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a table.I want to get selected checkbox value.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    @item
    <input type="hidden" value="@item" name="@item" class="chkbx" id="ControllerName" />
  </td>
  <td>                    
    <input type="checkbox" id="Iscreate" value="@Create" class="chkbx" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IsDelete" value="@Delete" class="chkbx" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IsView" value="@View" class="chkbx" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IsEdit" value="@Edit" class="chkbx" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="IsDownload" value="@Download" class="chkbx" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Jquery code I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
    var vales = $("#ControllerName").val();
    var vals = $('input[class=chkbx]:checked').map(function () {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().join(',');
    $('#debug').val(vals);
  });
</script>
```

---

Basically this code create a Value in hidden Field Like this

> 3-Create-Account,3-Delete-Account,3-View-Account,3-Edit-Account,3-Download-Account

But Actually i need this

> 3-Account-Create-Delete-Edit-Download-view,4-Account-Create-Delete-Edit-Download-view, 5-Account-Create-Delete-Edit-Download-view

I'm totally Confused :(

Comment: Yes using form collection .I just need to create this value which are defined in post using jquery

Comment: OMG. Use a view model and strongly typed html helpers, then post back the model

Comment: this basically use for create operation date gets from different table and save to different table that's why i use html and i dn't need to use Strongly typed......

Comment: Whats that got to do with not doing it the right way?

Comment: Stephan Muecke Can u help to create this Plz share your skype .

Comment: @RichardRay, Its not really clear what your doing here, but vortex has given an answer showing the basics of how you should be doing this - although you probably also want an ID property in the view model, and since you have a table, I assume the model is a collection in which case you need to render each row in a `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

Make a view model with your wanted properties:

```
public class YouViewModelName()
{

    public bool IsView {get; set;}
    public bool IsDeleted{get; set;}
    public bool IsCreated{get; set;}
    public bool IsEdited{get; set;}
    ......... and so on
}
```

Then use this view model in your view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsView)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsDeleted)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsCreated)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsEdited)
```

and so on...

When you post the form to your post action, you will get the values.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostActionName(ViewModelName viewModel)
{
 //use values here
}
```